# C - Noob error with simple 3-way comparison

Tags: c, getch

Apologies for the dumb question, I'm a bit of a beginner and am having trouble understanding why the following code will not work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int j = ' ';
    int check = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter A, B, or C\n");
    j = getch();

    while(check == 0)
    {
        if(j != 'A' || 'B' || 'C')
        {
            printf("\nInvalid entry, please enter either an A, B, or C\n");
            j = getch();
        }
        else
        {
            check = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

All I want this simple program to do is take in either A, B, or C using `getch()` (Yes, I need to use `getch()`) and use my `while` loop to confirm the entry actually is either an A, a B, or a C.  However, I run the program, and even when I enter an A, B, or a C, the program tells me my entry is not valid.  Can someone help me here and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that it reads in the character as an ASCII integer, but I'm really not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that `getch()` is a platform-specific function declared in `<conio.h>` on Windows and in `<curses.h>` on Unix (where its use also requires at least one setup function call). However, the use of `getch()` is actually tangential to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(j != 'A' || 'B' || 'C')
```

is equivalent to

```
if(j != 'A' || 'B' != 0 || 'C' != 0)
```

Both `'B'` and `'C'` have non-zero value so the condition will always evaluate true.

I think you want to check that `j` isn't any of the values listed.  If so, the line should be

```
if(j != 'A' && j != 'B' && j != 'C')
```

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following replacements:

```
int j = ' '; /* to */  char j = ' ';

if(j != 'A' || 'B' || 'C') /* to */ if(j != 'A' && j != 'B' && j != 'C')

j = getch(); /* to */ j=getchar();
```

Also, for getchar() to work, include `<conio.h>` if required.